# Resize an image whithout scaling it

Tags: android

I'm trying to resize a viewGroup from the right to the left. Inside my viewgroup I have some images. I tried to put all the scaletype values. The problem is that my images are getting scaled. I want them not too move.

What I want is basically resize my view and not see the image being scaled. Like if the view was hide by something going in front of it. I'm doing an animation so the goal is suposed to simulate a hidding motion. Like a truck passing in front of a car, the car is not scaled, just hide. The car is my view and the truck the width. I don't want to hide it with another view in front of it by making a translation. If possible i don't want to touch to my images, I already put the centerCrop value, but if you have a solution with it, share it please lol.
I don't have the code under my hands right now so I can't show you, but if you have any idea, thanks to share ;).

Comment: you will need to post code. The most common problem here is that you are using XML elements or other `View` parameters incorrectly, or the defaults are not what you expect.

Comment: As @Jim pointed out we need to see your XML. There are a number of possibilities. Your animations could be setup incorrectly, or your layouts could create view relationships/dependencies you aren't expecting. For example, a linear layout will not allow one view to "hide" behind another as easily as, say, a relative layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the track. Wraping my view of a linearLayout and resize it instead of the relative make it good. Because when we resize the relativeLayout it kind of modify/scale what is inside, with the linearlayout it does not move.